# ionic 2 native youtube video player can't play this video

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am making a app in ionic 2 and I need a youtube player. So I integrated ionic 2 native player. But it is showing an error "Can't play this video" on running the app on android emulator.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui3jy.png)

Answer (score 0):

You must use the Ionic Youtube Plugin

To install it, go to your Ionic project in the command line:

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/Glitchbone/CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer.git
npm install --save @ionic-native/youtube-video-player
```

Basic Usage:

```
import { YoutubeVideoPlayer } from '@ionic-native/youtube-video-player';

constructor(private youtube: YoutubeVideoPlayer) { }

  OpenVideo(){

this.youtube.openVideo('myvideoid');
 }
```

Of course 'myvideoid' is your youtube video ID passed as a string.

Comment: I have added it but still it doesn't work. 
My ionic info:
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.1.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.10.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002

Comment: this.youtube.openVideo('myvideoid');
this function dose  nothing in my emulator

Comment: @HaSnenTai I have edited my answer , call the function anywhere in the html